# Can't populate a HashMap with inputs

Tags: java, regex, parameters, struts2, struts2-interceptors

I have some inputs like this in a loop:

```
<s:hidden name="sequence['%{#currentEvent.idChain}']" value="%{#currentEvent.sequenceSpace}"/>
```

And, in my java file, I have

```
private HashMap<String, String> sequence;
public HashMap<String, String> getSequence() {
    return sequence;
}
public void setSequence(HashMap<String, String> sequence) {
    this.sequence = sequence;
}
```

But, for each inputs generated in my jsp, my console shows that:

```
Parameter [sequence['df18df5e-31ca-457e-89c1-14c0ab84e25c']] didn't match acceptedPattern pattern!
```

so my HashMap is *null*

Comment: **didn't match acceptedPattern pattern!** 
What didn't matched? Any error logs?

Comment: it is the only message i have in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

In Struts 2, parameters are handled by the [Parameters Interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/parameters-interceptor.html).

Looking in the source code, you will see

```
public static final String ACCEPTED_PARAM_NAMES = "\\w+((\\.\\w+)|(\\[\\d+\\])|(\\(\\d+\\))|(\\['\\w+'\\])|(\\('\\w+'\\)))*";
```

that means it uses the following regular expression to validate the input:

```
\w+(
    (\.\w+)     |
    (\[\d+\])   |
    (\(\d+\))   |
    (\['\w+'\]) |
    (\('\w+'\))
)*
```

[In Java](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html),

> `\w` stands for "word character". It always matches the ASCII characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

, then it accepts ASCII **letters**, **numbers**, and **underscores**, nothing more.

The minus signs in the middle of your hash

> `sequence['df18df5e-31ca-457e-89c1-14c0ab84e25c']`

are breaking the regex, causing the parameters to not being accepted.

The solution is: create a regex that will accept the minus sign inside the brackets, by expading the `\w` and adding a `-` at the end:

```
 \w+(
    (\.\w+)                 |
    (\[\d+\])               |
    (\(\d+\))               |
    (\['[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+'\]) |
    (\('[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+'\))
)*
```

that in Java is

```
"\w+((\.\w+)|(\[\d+\])|(\(\d+\))|(\['[A-Za-z0-9_\\-]+'\])|(\('[A-Za-z0-9_\\-]+'\)))*"
```

All you have to do now is to override the default regex with your custom regex by passing it to the Interceptor as parameter (the example is with convention plugin, but it's the same when using struts.xml):

```
@Action( value = "yourAction", 
         results = @Result( location = "/yourPage.jsp" ),
         interceptorRefs = @InterceptorRef ( 
                            value = "defaultStack", 
                           params = { "params.acceptParamNames", 
                                      "\w+((\.\w+)|(\[\d+\])|(\(\d+\))|(\['[A-Za-z0-9_\\-]+'\])|(\('[A-Za-z0-9_\\-]+'\)))*"
                                    }
                           )
       )
```